# How many memory locations of the main memory will map to each cache location?

Tags: assembly, mips

I am studying for a test and am stuck on this question from my study guide. Can someone explain how to solve this question?

For a main memory with 2^10 word (10 address bits) and a direct mapped cache with 2^4 words(4 index bits), how many memory locations of the main memory will map to each cache location?

Thanks!

Comment: how many address locations does 2 to the fourth get you?

Comment: and how bit is each address location?

Answer (score 0):

The cache contains 16 words. Main memory contains 1024 words. This is a direct mapped cache so 1024/16 = 64 memory words map to each cache location.